# How to save Highlights marked on a JTextArea?

Tags: java, highlight

I'm working on a university assignment in which I have to make a e-book application with cliente-server approach.

The thing is that in a view that is used by the reader(A class) to read all his books, the reader can highlight the text he desires

this is the code:

```
  private void ButtonResaltarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (TextAreaLibro.getSelectedText() != null) { // See if they selected something 
            String selected_text = TextAreaLibro.getSelectedText();
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, selected_text);

            Highlighter highlighter = TextAreaLibro.getHighlighter();
            HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.yellow);
            int p0 = this.TextAreaLibro.getText().indexOf(selected_text);
            int p1 = p0 + selected_text.length();
            try {
                highlighter.addHighlight(p0, p1, painter);
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(InternalVistaLectura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, the reader must be able to save all the highlights he made in the text on a specific book (this text of the book is contained in a ArrayList), every book has it's own ISBN which is unique to every book. Here is where I'm lost, I was thinking of an HashMap on the reader class to store all the highlights, this HashMap will have as key the ISBN of the book, and the value mapped to that key will be an ArrayList containing all the indexes of the highlighted substrings, this is just an vague idea, I hope you could help me with this problem in any way I can guide me with your answers.

Thanks

> NOTE:
>   I've found that Highlighter class have a method called `getHighlights()` this method fetches all the Highlights to an array `Highlight[]`, however couldn't find much information about this Highlight class.

Comment: I'd consider a second model, which you would then use to create and apply the `Highlight`s from, but which would maintain information about the highlights so that they can be recreated

Comment: Have you seen the documentation for the [`Highlight`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.Highlight.html) class? It lets you get the start and end points of the highlighted text.